# Programmatic auto-layout not calculating height of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, autolayout, programmatically-created

I have a a `UIViewController` which has a header area. At the bottom of that header element is a row of UIButtons. Below these buttons, I've placed a `UIScrollView`, within which is embedded a `UIView` called `contentContainer`. Within that container is a number of `UILabels` and `UIViews` styled as dividers.

The entire ViewController, all subviews, and their associated auto-layout constraints are constructed programmatically.

Everything seems to work well, with the exception that the UIScrollView is not vertically scrolling. If I explicitly give the `contentContainer` subview a size with an auto-layout height constraint, it works.

This leads me to think that height of the contentContainer is not being accurately computed.

Example of how each UI element is built:

```
let divider1: UIView = {
    let divider = UIView()
    divider.backgroundColor = Colors.white10
    divider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return divider
}()
```

My viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addSubview(buttonClose)
    self.view.addSubview(labelPlaceTitle)
    self.view.addSubview(buttonShare)
    self.view.addSubview(buttonRoute)
    self.view.addSubview(buttonDelete)
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    scrollView.addSubview(contentContainer)

    contentContainer.addSubview(divider1)
    contentContainer.addSubview(labelAddressLabel)
    contentContainer.addSubview(labelAddressActual)
    contentContainer.addSubview(divider2)
    contentContainer.addSubview(labelDateLabel)
    contentContainer.addSubview(labelDateActual)
    contentContainer.addSubview(divider3)
    contentContainer.addSubview(labelNoteLabel)
    contentContainer.addSubview(labelNoteActual)
    contentContainer.addSubview(buttonAddNote)
    contentContainer.addSubview(divider4)

    setupLayout()
}
```

My auto-layout constraints:

```
private func setupLayout() {
    buttonClose.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    buttonClose.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    buttonClose.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28).isActive = true
    buttonClose.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28).isActive = true

    labelPlaceTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 48).isActive = true
    labelPlaceTitle.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    labelPlaceTitle.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true

    buttonShare.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelPlaceTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    buttonShare.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    buttonShare.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true
    buttonShare.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true

    buttonRoute.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelPlaceTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    buttonRoute.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonShare.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    buttonRoute.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true
    buttonRoute.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true

    buttonDelete.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelPlaceTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    buttonDelete.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonRoute.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    buttonDelete.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true
    buttonDelete.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true

    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonRoute.bottomAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = true
    scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    contentContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    contentContainer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    contentContainer.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    contentContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    contentContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    contentContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    contentContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    divider1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.topAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    divider1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    divider1.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
    divider1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

    labelAddressLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: divider1.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    labelAddressLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    labelAddressLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true

    labelAddressActual.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelAddressLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
    labelAddressActual.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    labelAddressActual.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true

    divider2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelAddressActual.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    divider2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    divider2.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
    divider2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

    labelDateLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: divider2.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    labelDateLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    labelDateLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true

    labelDateActual.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelDateLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
    labelDateActual.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    labelDateActual.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true

    divider3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelDateActual.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    divider3.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    divider3.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
    divider3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true

    labelNoteLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: divider3.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    labelNoteLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    labelNoteLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true

    labelNoteActual.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelNoteLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
    labelNoteActual.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    labelNoteActual.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true

    buttonAddNote.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelNoteActual.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    buttonAddNote.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    buttonAddNote.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
    buttonAddNote.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true

    divider4.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonAddNote.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    divider4.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    divider4.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.rightAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
    divider4.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
}
```

}

And a shot of the UI, with the light grey portion of the sheet representing the `contentContainer`:

[Screenshot of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7l1j.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The ScrollView’s frame could be small than content size, that’s a natural behavior, think about it. If you want the frame size to equal to contentSize, you should do it your own.  If you want automatic height calculation, you should make a custom contentView wrapping all your subviews to achieve this.

Comment: In the instances I'm testing, the content _is larger_ than the `UIScrollView` frame—I think `contentContainer` is the custom view you're referring to, and I'm hoping to have it be calculated based on auto-layout constraints.

Comment: OK,  If you want a custom view could automatically calculate it’s height. 3 things should be confirmed. 1. The top constraint should be related to the top subview’s top.  2. The bottom constraint should be related to the bottom subview’s bottom. 3. All subviews constraints should be unambiguous and there height should be resolvable by the Auto Layout system.  : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compute the height of your `contentContainer`, *Auto Layout* needs an unbroken chain of subviews from the top of `contentContainer` to the bottom.  In your case, you seem to have that chain except that your bottommost view is not connected to the bottom of the `contentContainer`.

Add a constraint connecting the bottom of `divider4` to the bottom of `contentContainer`.  This will allow *Auto Layout* to compute the size of `contentContainer`.

Also, you shouldn't set these constraints:

```
contentContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
contentContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! 

I added `divider4.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true` and unfortunately it still isn't working.

Any thoughts on why?

Comment: I don't think you want the `contentContainer.centerYAnchor` and `contentContainer.centerXAnchor` constraints.  Try commenting those out.

Comment: Ah—you nailed it! Thanks so much for your help. Adding the `divider4` bottomAnchor to `contentContainer` as you specified above and removing the centerX and centerY anchors solved it.